# CKEditor and InsertHTML in IE 8: inserts at beginning of text

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, insert, cursor, ckeditor

I have a strange problem with CKEditor, InsertHTML and IE8. I've made a plugin which sums up all pages made in my CMS, and you can pick one and click OK to insert a link to it in your page. This is working perfectly in Chrome and FF, but for some strange reason it reacts strange in IE8 (haven't tested earlier versions of IE). If I select a page and click OK, the link isn't inserted in the place where I last put my cursor. It is inserted at the beginning of the page. I've read about the problem on the internet, but couldn't really make up something of it. (P.S. It works with all the other standard plugins from CK).
Here is the code which inserts the HTML if the OK button is clicked:

```
onOk: function()
{
     this._.editor.insertHtml(iframeWindow.document.getElementById("insertHTML").value);
}
```

I hope anyone else has had this problem and has solved it, or if you haven't had it but know the problem.

Thanks in advance!
Duco

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the api.html sample and it's working fine for me with IE8. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Hmm, I forgot to add one stupid detail, it works fine with all other plugins of CKEditor. I've already installed the newest version of CKEditor. Thanks for the answer ;)